# If someone says you're being silly and you don't know why, should you ask 何ですか？ or なぜですか？

Tags: word-choice, conversations

I'm confused because in sites like [this](http://mylanguages.org/japanese_questions.php) one.

They define 何ですか as what and なぜですか as why. But in other sides I saw 何ですか defined as why too.

So, what would be the best way to handle the question in the title (I'm open to other options.)

Example conversation:

> Speaker A: Dude, you're being cringey now.
>
> Speaker B: Why (do you say that)?

Comment: I wouldn't use either of those as Speaker B...

Comment: @istrasci why not? I mean, is there a better way to handle that? Maybe どうしてそう思うか？

Comment: I'd probably say something like えっ、なんで？It seems most natural for casual conversation.

Comment: ^ ＠eric ううん、「どうしてそう思う**か** ？」なんて言わない。

Comment: @ericfromabeno こういうのは、「か」は「どうしてそう思いますか」とかのほうが使うんだね

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most natural response to that would be probably be some form of why: なぜ, なんで, or どうして. But 何ですか would make sense if you interpreted it as "What is it (in my conduct that you think is cringey)?" In both cases you're asking for some sort of explanation but with a different nuance. The likely reason for 何ですか being considered a "why" is because in some contexts you can use it to get an explanation but not always.

Basically, if you want *reasons* you should ask with a "why" question, and if you want *things* you should ask a "what" question.

Comment: So  なぜ, なんで, or どうして are like the short/informal versions of なぜですか ?

Comment: @alex Yes. By themselves they are informal but they can all be made formal by adding ですか  after them.

Answer (score 3):

何ですか doesn't mean "why", but 何でですか? or simply 何で? mean "why".